# Heroku Local [WARN] No ENV file found

Tags: heroku

When I run `heroku local`

my console shows me:

> [WARN] No ENV file found

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you had any problems aside from the `[WARN]` message displaying? I get the same error message, but it doesn't affect my development.

Answer (score 30):

Add an `.env` file. This files contains the local `VARS` that are different in your local setting from the heroku environment. However, if everything runs fine, you can just ignore the warning, or do `touch .env`.

You can also differentiate by creating a `Procfile.local` file and run `heroku local -f Procfile.local`, to force using a local start script.

I just read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local. That explains it all.

For a working example: http://github.com/halcwb/GenUnitApp.git. When you have the heroku toolbelt installed you can `heroku local -f Procfile.bash` on mac or linux, or `heroku -f Procfile.local` for windows, and go to http://localhost:3000, to check the result.

Comment: What does this file look like? What is the structure of it? Do you have an example? I'm running into this problem and I'm running it locally.

Comment: I'm using `Config` library to mange my environments, so i do not have `.env` file, how to make heroku ignore this fact ?. 

It work fine when i deploy to Heroku, but fails locally.
I tried:

`heroku local web` which fires `npm run build && node dist/Server` // `[WARN] No ENV file found`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386493/heroku-local-warn-no-env-file-found-when-using-config-library-to-manage-enviro