# Heroku localhost stuck on "[WARN] No ENV File Found" for a Node.js App

Tags: node.js, heroku, localhost

I have a Node.js App which works fine when deployed to Heroku but whenever I try to test it locally using "heroku local" or "heroku local web -f Procfile", it gets stuck on while showing "[WARN] No ENV File Found".

Answer (score 3):

> Add an .env file. This files contains the local VARS that are different in your local setting from the heroku environment. However, if everything runs fine, you can just ignore the warning, or do touch .env.
>
> You can also differentiate by creating a Procfile.local file and run heroku local -f Procfile.local, to force using a local start script.
>
> I just read: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local. That explains it all.
>
> For a working example: http://github.com/halcwb/GenUnitApp.git. When you have the heroku toolbelt installed you can heroku local -f Procfile.bash on mac or linux, or heroku -f Procfile.local for windows, and go to http://localhost:3000, to check the result.

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690780/heroku-local-warn-no-env-file-found)

Comment: using "run heroku local -f Procfile.local" gets me somewhere but not quite. I am getting Windows Script Host Error with code 800A138F for my main.js Following is the log:
`$ heroku local web -f Procfile.local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\uwBot\Procfile.local'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
4:02:11 AM web.1 |  > uwbot@1.0.0 start C:\Program Files\nodejs\uwBot
4:02:11 AM web.1 |  > main.js
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
4:02:55 AM web.1 Exited Successfully`