# Heroku local [WARN] No ENV file found when using Config library to manage environments

Tags: heroku, config, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I'm using [`Config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) library to mange my environments, so i do not have `.env` file, how to make heroku ignore this fact ?.

It work fine when i deploy to Heroku, but fails locally.
I tried:

`heroku local web` which fires `npm run build && node dist/Server` // `[WARN] No ENV file found`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make Heroku remove this warning is to create a `.env` file.
This warning shouldn't be problematic in itself though, as it shouldn't prevent your app from running.